# ArcPad 10 - VBScript Error 800A0046

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpad, trimble, vb, juno

A colleague asked me to install ArcPad 10 on his Trimble JUNO 3B.  He runs an application with scripts that produce messages when the GPS is turned off.  The script works fine on his Trimble Nomad - but on the new Juno he gets the following error:

VBScript runtime error 800A0046 "permission denied: 'MsgBox("message")'

The error quotes line 4534 column 2 which has nothing to do with the msgbox.

Basically the message that should pop up is something along the lines of 'you can't do that, there is no GPS fix'

I have no skill whatsoever with VB and have no desire to learn.  Any one know if there is a quick fix aside from telling my colleague to figure it out on his own?  Could this be an issue with the Juno using a different OS than the Nomad?  Or perhaps a different version of ArcPad?

Comment: A quick Google on error "800A0046" seems to suggest it's a permission issue, what is on line 4534?

Comment: The permission error seems to be server related but its not running on a server.  It runs on a handheld unit completely away from any connectivity.  The line 4534 (which is a different line depending on the program editor you use) is actually the following:
___________________________________________________
msgbox "Please turn on GPS and try again.", 16, "eSilv Error"


Should msgbox have capital letters?

Comment: I've been censored as off-topic I guess... I guess my solution is to send his issue to ESRI and hope for help.

Comment: Solution:  

Uninstall VBScript Runtime Library and Install again... seems to work now